# Time capsule speed issues

Tags: time-capsule

Whenever I browse my Time Capsule's AirPort Disk, it seems very slow in simply listing the files it has. I am looking in directories with upwards of fifty music files in each.

Scrolling is really slow. I have turned of Icon Preview in the View Options etc. But it's still slow.

Anyone know how I can speed it up?

Thanks.

Comment: USB is a slow connection in any case. Is it a lot worse when attached to the Time Capsule than it is attached directly to your computer with USB?    Also, is speed a problem when using the Time Capsule's internal drive?

Comment: It's when accessing the TC's own internal drive over Wi-Fi

Answer (score 1):

This is the nature of wireless networks and Apple's AFP protocol. I'd reccomend either connecting to a wired network to browse your music, or using the command line to find what you're looking for, as Finder adds a deal of latency to the file-listing process.

Comment: Wired network is the way to go. Remember that 480Mbps is an absolute maximum and includes all the overhead associated with data transmitting.